# laravel-adminのインストール時の Syntax error

Tags: php, laravel

ローカル環境にlaravelをインストールしています。
それ自体は正常に動作したのですが、続いてlaravel-adminのインストールでエラーが発生して躓いています。

インストールしたのは「laravel-admin#v1.4.5」です
https://packagist.org/packages/encore/laravel-admin#v1.4.5

色々と調べながらmigrateまでは完了したのですが

```
php artisan migrate
```

installコマンドを実行するところでエラーが発生します。

```
php artisan admin:install
```

表示されるエラーは以下のとおりです

---

Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '' (SQL: create table `` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `username` varchar(190) not null, `password` var
  char(60) not null, `name` varchar(191) not null, `avatar` varchar(191) null, `remember_token` varchar(100) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 colla
  te utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name

---

DBを見る限りは
password_resets
migrations
users
などのテーブルが作成されていました。

エラーの原因はどのようなものが考えられるでしょうか。

Comment: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/issues/567
 や https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=9251 のように、1103 Incorrect table nameの後ろが空白であればそれを修正する必要があります。

Answer (score 1):

すいません、自己解決しました。
初歩的な手順が抜けていたようで、以下のコマンド実行後に
インストール実行で無事、エラーを回避できました。

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-admin

php artisan admin:install
```